# How to count the content of a javascript object which exists multple times

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So i have got a page with about 12 bounding boxes, each of these boxes has 6 checkboxes where when a checkox will be checked/unchecked an object is getting a value using v-model.

Now i need a dynamic badge that shows the number of each selected checkbox.

The following is unique for every Bounding Box and the one that i need is the selection[] object.
While i can get the length of the object for one single Bounding Box by using Object.keys(selection).length i dont really know how to count together the lengths of multiple of these objects.

```
                            v.clickboxes.push({
                                id:arraySelects[i].getAttribute('id'), 
                                x:bb.x,
                                y:bb.y,
                                width:bb.width,
                                height:bb.height,                          

                                settings:{
                                    selection:[],  
                                    }
                            });
```

My try to counting the length of the selection object is to create a method that is getting called whenever a checkbox is clicked and as a parameter the function is getting the selection object.

```
 badgenumber:function(selection)
                        {
                            var v = this;

                            v.badgeamount  = Object.keys(selection).length;

                            console.log(v.badgeamount);
                      
                        },
```

Like this it is always only getting the value of the current Bounding Box selected while it is still off because when you check the first checkbox it has the value 0 and when you uncheck a bounding box it still counts up.

I was told to use a for loop to kind of count all of the elements in all of the selection objects together and then asign that to a variable but i dont really know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a function that you call once you check a box!

So you can add a property of type array [in the global scope] that is accessible by all 12 bounding boxes and once you check a box inside any bounding box, you reach outside that bounding box to store the number of each selected checkbox in that property.

Comment: I tried that and i can count up with .push(selection) but how can i count down again. Or better said how do i check if the different selection objects have been asigned a new element or not when the method is getting called?

Comment: Counting down is easy, you can ad an if-else statement at the beginning of the function you call when a checkbox gets clicked, and check if the item you click has its data in the global scope property of type array, or does not. If found, then use get its index in that array using `.findIndex()` function and then remove its data from the array using `.splice()` function

Comment: I tried to do that but i failed at the if statements because all of the checkboxes are the same for each boudning box and they all model the same value, 1-6. So if i for example .push(selection) into my global variable with the value 1 and then for another box i also push 1 into the global variable, how does my if statement look like to check for only one "1" and to remove only one "1".

Comment: Use a function for each checkbox that has parameter of (the checkbox value, the bounding box, ...) and inside the function you can push to the array what you already have from that function